# how to compare non rectangular ROI using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, difference, parking

I want to detect parking lot,
I already detect each slot using `cv2.findcontour` and draw it `cv2.drawContours(imgB, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)`.

Then I want to compare the difference between reference image and input image from cctv using `compare_ssim`.

The problem is, contour that I use is not rectangular. I can't compare using ssim. Is there any way to compare non rectangular ROI?

I have tried to create `boundingRect` and compare, but the result is inaccurate, because the ROI that I want to compare is intersected with other ROI. `compare_ssim` can't compare non-rectangular ROI. I try `(score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA[[c]], grayB[[c]], full=True)`, but that gives me an error like this

> IndexError: index 463 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 360!

I expect the output is know the specific empty or not empty parking slot.
But at this point I just want to compare the difference with non rectangular ROI.

Comment: Is it ok to compare 2 bounding boxes of contours?

Comment: ya, i did, actually with bounding rectangle, not boxes

 (score, diff) = compare_ssim(grayA[y:y+h, x:x+w], grayB[y:y+h, x:x+w], full=True)
 diff = (diff * 255).astype("uint8")